# php dbase extension cutting off float point numbers

Tags: php, dbase

I have weird problem with php reading dbase (dbf) files.

**My development environment**

- OS: Win 7
- Php version: 5.3.8
- Web server: apache 2.2

**My production environment**

- OS: Centos 5.5
- Php version: 5.3.12
- Web server: nginx 1.2.1

Both those environments use standard php dbase extension (unix: http://pecl.php.net/package/dbase, win: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).

I have dbf file where one column is float (10,2) with value, lets say, 26.14. When I read this file in my development environment it shows correctly ("26.14"), but doing the exact same operation on production environment it outputs just "26". Code follows:

```
<?php
$db = dbase_open($path_to_dbf, 0);
$record_numbers = dbase_numrecords($db);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $record_numbers; $i++)
{
   $row = dbase_get_record_with_names($db, $i);
   echo '<pre>', var_dump($row), '</pre>'; 
}
?>
```

I'm really confused and don't know where to start looking for solution to this problem. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Check library versions. Show them of both systems. Then compare. There might be a sign of difference. Also check if there is some configuration somewhere.

Comment: doing `phpversion('dbase');` outputs nothing. Is there any other way to check library version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old question, but maybe it'll help someone.

Probably you have an "," as separator, instead of "."

I have that problem and this helps:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
```